# Is the "Intent is user-configurable" checkbox missing in Xcode 10.2 for iOS12.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios12, xcode10.2

I'm trying to develop a Siri Shortcut for my app that would appear in Apple's Shortcuts app. After reading this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app I found what I was looking for in the "Define User-Configurable Shortcuts" section towards the bottom.

Unfortunately that checkbox does not exist in my installation of Xcode (10.2 and a deployment target running iOS 12.2) does not seem to have that key "Intent is user-configurable checkbox" checkbox.

Are user-configurable shortcuts not going to be available until iOS 13? Do I basically have to upgrade my setup to include iOS13 targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Shortcuts only become configurable when building with the iOS 13 (which can only be done with Xcode 11).